# How to tell which sentences expressing purposes & which ones expressing reasons?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

In [Collins COBUILD English Usage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for):

> **for**
>
> If something is **for** someone, they are intended to have it or benefit from it.
>
> *He left a note for her on the table.*
>
> *She held out the flowers and said, 'They're for you.'*
>
> *I am doing everything I can for you.*
>
> You use **for** in front of a noun phrase or **-ing form** when you
>   state the **purpose** of an object, action, or activity.
>
> Some planes are for internal use, others for international flights.
>
> The mug had been used for mixing flour and water.
>
> You use **for** in front of a noun phrase when you are saying **why**
>   someone does something.
>
> *We stopped for lunch by the roadside.*
>
> *I went to the store for a newspaper.*
>
> *Be Careful!*
>
> Don't use '**for**' with an -ing form when you saying **why** someone
>   does something.
>
> Don't say, for example, '*He went to the city for finding work*'.
>
> You say '*He went to the city to find work*' or '*He went to the city
>   in order to find work*'.
>
> *People would stroll down the path to admire the garden.*
>
> *He had to hurry in order to reach the next place on his schedule.*

Ok, the dictionary says that "*I went to the store for a newspaper.*" expressing a reason (The reason I went to the store is that I want to buy a newspaper).

However, I would say that "*I went to the store for a newspaper.*" also expresses a purpose (I went to the store with a purpose, that is I want to buy a newspaper)

So, **How to tell which sentences expressing purposes & which ones expressing reasons?**

For example, I do we know that this sentence "*I went to the store for a newspaper.*" expresses a reason but not a purpose?? **a reason & a purpose are almost the same.**

Note: we need to know that because the dictionary says:

*Don't use '**for**' with an -ing form when you saying **why** someone
does something.*

Answer (score 1):

The reason the book makes the distinction between "purposes" and "reasons why" is only to prevent a specific grammar error with "for + -ing form". I don't think they did a great job of explaining things, but hopefully this clears things up for you.

---

### Purposes

> You use for in front of a noun phrase or -ing form when you state the purpose of an object, action, or activity.

I think "an object, action, or activity" means *noun* here, where "for X" is essentially an adjective (see ["Purpose Adjectives"](https://www.espressoenglish.net/order-of-adjectives-in-english/)). It's not a perfect comparison (there are subtle differences between these pairs), but you should get the idea:

> - 1.
>
>   - A bowl for mixing
>   - A mixing bowl
> - 2.
>
>   - Some planes are for internal use
>   - Internal use planes

---

### Reasons Why

(It's important not to call it "reasons", since the words "reason" and "purpose" are synonyms. The "why" is important.)

Sentences expressing a "reason why" can easily be detected by forming a "why question" and answer pair:

> We stopped for lunch by the roadside.
>
> - Why did we stop? For lunch by the roadside.
>
> I went to the store for a newspaper.
>
> - Why did I go to the store? For a newspaper.

You can use this method to see if "for" or "to" is right; "to" is appropriate in this example because the response to 2 doesn't sound right:

> He went to the city [to find/for finding] work.
>
> 1. Why did he go to the city? To find work.
> 2. Why did he go to the city? * For finding work.

Note that you cannot say "I went to the store to a newspaper".

---

### Overlap

Sometimes both "for" or "to" can be used interchangeably without changing the sentence much (if at all):

> The mug had been used for mixing flour and water.
>
> The mug had been used to mix flour and water.

Comment: Here is a simpler explanation http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/for-ing. "We don’t use for + -ing to express our purpose or intention. We use to + infinitive"

Answer (score 0):

- "I went to to the store **for a** newspaper" (there's no verb after *for* so the problem of the  -ing suffix doesn't exist)
- "I went to the store **to buy** a newspaper" *to buy* expresses the reason.
- "I read newspapers **for the** news" Why do I buy a newspaper? To read the news.
- "I use newspapers **for lining** a birdcage" *Q:* What do I use a newspaper for? What is its *function*? *A*: *[To line the bottom of my birdcage](http://www.birdtricks.com/blog/how-old-is-the-newspaper-that-you-use-to-line-your-birds-cage/)*.